# Array Combining Values

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I have an array that looks like this:

```
guest_list = ['P', 'r', 'o', 'f', '.', ' ', 'P', 'l', 'u', 'm', '\n', 'M', 'i', 's', 's', ' ', 'S', 'c', 'a', 'r', 'l', 'e', 't', '\n', 'C', 'o', 'l', '.', ' ', 'M', 'u', 's', 't', 'a', 'r', 'd', '\n', 'A', 'l', ' ', 'S', 'w', 'e', 'i', 'g', 'a', 'r', 't', '\n', 'R', 'o', 'b', 'o', 'c', 'o', 'p']
```

What I want is an array that looks like this:

```
guest_list = ['Prof.Plum', 'Miss Scarlet', 'Col. Mustard', 'Al Sweigart', 'Robocop']
```

In other words, until '\n' appears, I want all of the string values to be combined into 1 value.

Any suggestions?

Edit #1:

Here is part of my original code:

```
ogl = open('guests.txt') #open guest list
pyperclip.copy(ogl.read()) #open guest list copy
guest_list = list(pyperclip.paste())
```

Comment: It would be nice of you to put /some/ effort into your question. For example, your expected output is invalid. Also, in Python we call this "list" not "array". You should also show us what you have tried so far and how it has failed instead of expecting us to do your work for you. (And I'm even ignoring the fact that your input is very unlikely to occur unless you have some serious problems elsewhere in your code.)

Comment: I'm sorry. I am new to Python. I have like 1 month of experience using it :)

Comment: How did you get this list? It looks like there's some bad upstream processing that should be adjusted, like a `list` call on a string or a loop over individual characters.

Comment: I am reading a book and that was one of the sample files provided.

Comment: Do you read in your string using something like `[character for character in your_string]`?  If so, you should instead use `your_string.split('\n')` from the beginning to avoid have to `join` later.

Comment: I edited my post to show how I got the original input into my list.

Comment: Ah yea, calling list on a string creates an list of each character, call `pyperclip.paste().split('\n')`

Comment: so guest_list = pyperclip.paste().split('\n') ? like that?

Comment: Yes, that will work.  I'm confused as to what the purpose of copying and pasting is here however, instead of just calling `split('\n')` on `ogl.read()`  You could even use `ogl.read().splitlines()`

Comment: Oh, the task is to open a text document and paste into a word document.

Comment: I am good now, thanks for the help everyone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply use [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) and [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
>>> ''.join(x).split('\n')
['Prof. Plum', 'Miss Scarlet', 'Col. Mustard', 'Al Sweigart', 'Robocop']
```

Since you've updated your question to show how you read in the file, here is what you really should be doing:

```
with open('guests.txt') as ogl:
    pyperclip.copy(ogl.read())
    guest_list = pyperclip.paste().split('\n')
```

Or something along those lines, although I'm not sure why you are doing the copy/paste thing.

Comment: I am pasting into a word doc and I am very new to Python. I am importing a text and pasting into a word doc.

Comment: Ah, alright, I'm not familiar with the pyperclip library.